# Line break replacing first value in char array

Tags: c, arrays

I am having a problem with a simple array. Where suddenly the first value (i.e `names[0]`) is replaced with a line break

```
functionOne(names[PLAYERS][NAME_LEN]);
function2(names[PLAYERS][NAME_LEN]);
function2(names[PLAYERS][NAME_LEN]);

int main(void) {
    char names[PLAYERS][NAME_LEN];
    functionOne(names);
}

functionOne(names[PLAYERS][NAME_LEN])
{
   function1(names);
   function2(names);
}
```

The names are all initialised using a `scanf` like:

```
for (x=0; x < PLAYERS; x++){
    printf("Please enter the name of player %d: ", x + 1);
    fgets(names[x], NAME_LEN, stdin);
    //remove line break from the end of the fgets
    size_t length = strlen(names[x]);
    names[x][--length] = '\0';
}
```

Inside `function1` All I do that involves `names` is copy from one array to another like this:

```
if (score2 == 3)
{
    //player 2 won. So move to round 2
    strcpy(roundTwoNames[game - 1], names[player2]);
}
else
{
    //player 1 won. So move to round 2
    strcpy(roundTwoNames[game - 1], names[player1]);
}
printf("Here - %s", names[0]);
roundOneScores[player1] = score1;
roundOneScores[player2] = score2;
```

This also prints out the first value in the `names` array but that works fine.

But for some reason in `function2` When I print out the first value of the array like:

```
printf("%s", names[0]);
```

It returns just a line break?

If I enter `function2` before I enter `function1` It returns the names[0] perfectly.

Which therefore implies that `function1` must have the issue. But that is a lot of code which has nothing to do with the `names` array.

Do you know why this might be happening?

---

## EDIT:

This

```
if (matchesComplete == matches)
{
    printf("Here2 - %s", names[0]);
    
    round = round + 1;
    
    /* reset gamesPlayed count */
    for (x=0; x < 10; x++)
    {
        gamesPlayed[x] = 10;
    }
    
    if(round < 5)
    {
        printf("\nYou are now into round %d!\n", round);
        
        printf("Here3 - %s", names[0]);
    }
    
    break;
}
```

returns `here1` and `here2` but **not** `here3` Why is that?!!

Answer (score 0):

First off, you should not be using scanf, it is vulnerable for security attacks (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scanf_format_string, see security). With the format string %s, with no width specifier, you could effectively be overwriting the next variable in memory, if the name you enter is too long. So you should make sure that the format specifier should be something such as %19s, in NAME_LEN is 20.

Note that the scanf cannot know the width of the fields you reserved in memory. You have to protect the buffer!

The scanf is now considered so dangerous that it has been deprecated in recent compilers. Some compilers issue a warning, some just classify the function non-existing.

Note: @WhozCraig notified me scanf isn't deprecated. He's right - it seems only Microsoft did that.

**Edit:** Here's a hint:

```
printf("Test");    // will print only a line break, which isn't even from the
                   // from the print This is because the runtime routines will
                   // 'cache' the printed text till the next \n is to be
                   // be printed.
                   // So, if you want to print debug info, always do this:
printf("Text\n");  // This will force the print.
```

So, I think this explains your problems. If you call function2 before function1, your output doesn't work till function1 is called. The \n there will make the
output of function2 come out. Golden rule: ALWAYS add \n at the end of your printf texts (unless you *want* the text not to print till later).

Comment: I have updated my question with my new method of `scanf` But still the issue continues!

Comment: [`scanf`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fscanf) is *not* deprecated from the standard library. Some vendors (ex: Micro$oft) have deprecated it via warning as un-secure and fostered the likes of [`scanf_s()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/w40768et.aspx) in its place. Properly used `scanf()` is secure. It isn't like `scanf` is the new [`gets()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/gets), a hideous abomination so vile it arguably should never have been part of the standard library in the first place.

Comment: Yes, you're right about the micro$oft issue. I forgot to double check all MSDN info :) Most compilers do have tricks to add security though. Such as the G_GNUC_SCANF() which can enable type checking the variables. And use of scanf should always be accompanied by warnings...

Comment: Ok... The fgets solves the security problem. The "Here3" problem is probably the lack of a '\n' at the end of the text.

Answer (score -1):

```
//this code block contains a few errors.

for (x=0; x < PLAYERS; x++)
{
    printf("Please enter the name of player %d: ", x + 1);
    scanf("%s", names[x]);
}

//The errors are:
//1) scanf does not append a termination char to the string.
//2) the returned value from scanf() is not being checked
//   to assure the name was actually input successfully
//3) the format parameter of scanf() is not allowing for white space, like newlines

//suggest:
for (x=0; x < PLAYERS; x++)
{
    printf("Please enter the name of player %d: ", x + 1);
    if( 1 != scanf(" %s", names[x]) ) // notice the leading ' ' in the format parameter
    {
        // handle error
    }
}

//This code block contains an error:

functionOne(names[PLAYERS][NAME_LEN]);
function2(names[PLAYERS][NAME_LEN]);
function2(names[PLAYERS][NAME_LEN]);

//the errors are:
//there is two prototypes for function2() and no prototype for function1()
//the compiler will assume all parameters and return types for function1() are int.
//the return type for each function is not defined (the default is int)

//suggest:
void functionOne( player_t names[] );
void function1(   player_t names[] );
void function2(   player_t names[] );


//the current method of defining the function parameter:
names[PLAYERS][NAME_LEN] is very awkward.

//suggest:
typedef char player[NAME_LEN] player_t
//then creating an array of the player_t and init to all '\0'
player_t names[PLAYERS] = {{'\0'}};
```

Comment: I have updated my question with my new method of scanf But still the issue continues!

Comment: According to the manual of scanf, in case of an %s field: Matches a sequence of non-white-space characters; the next pointer must be a
 pointer  to  character  array that is long enough to hold the input sequence  and the terminating null byte ('\0'), **which  is  added  automatically**. The input  string  stops at white space or at the maximum field width, whichever occurs first.

Comment: @jcoppens as I said I am not using scanf any more!

Comment: @Maximilian, yes, I noticed (though the comment still mentions scanf, I believe). The comment above was for user3629249 who's comments have some problems. I'd really suggest you post a working section of your code where the problem appears. If we have to paste and glue, and complete what's missing, you might not be able to find a victim to debug it.